# How to locate Facebook POST button using Java Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, css

Code:

```
driver.findelement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='js_2y']/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/button")).click();
```

Every time I try by locating XPath, it's gives an exception, could not locate element.

```
May 04, 2016 8:35:29 PM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: .//*[@id='js_2y']/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/button)
```

Is it something that can be done using CSS selector. Not sure how to locate it. I see below path for it:

```
<button class="_1mf7 _4jy0 _4jy3 _4jy1 _51sy selected _42ft" data-testid="react-composer-post-button" type="submit" value="1">
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking about this post button - try below code to click on post button.

[image]

for this-

```
WebElement postBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Post')]"));
postBtn.click();
```

OR

```
WebElement postBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='_1mf7 _4jy0 _4jy3 _4jy1 _51sy selected _42ft']"));
postBtn.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the element with below xpath locator :

```
By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, '_1mf7 _4jy0 _4jy3 _4jy1 _51sy selected _42ft') and @type='submit']");
```

Hope it will help resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this just now.

Here my code:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("._1mf7._4jy0._4jy3._4jy1._51sy.selected._42ft").click()
```

Comment: Can you please explain why that worked?  What benefit does that solution give over other options?